# Flash vertical menu

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs6

I am making a flash website I am new to flash but I have to make this wewbsite for my wife. I created a button and added the code to action but it pops up the link instead of going to the link

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.net.navigateToURL;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.URLRequestMethod;

sramani.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_MouseClickHandler_2);
function fl_MouseClickHandler_2(event:MouseEvent):void
{

    var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.sramani.org");
    request.method = URLRequestMethod.GET;
    var target:String = "_blank"
    navigateToURL(request, target);
    // This example code displays the words "Mouse clicked" in the Output panel.
    trace("Mouse clicked");

}
```

I also have right button panel

I want to create drop down option for each button but I also want to button lower to the top to slide down.

Comment: what do you mean "pops up the link instead of going to the link"?

Comment: it opens the website in a new tab instead of opening in the same window/tab. I even changed _blank to _self. But it is still not working.

Comment: well, `_blank` is exactly for opening a link in a new tab so you had to change it. If `_self` does not work, try `_top`.

Comment: However, check the browser's settings as it may be set to opening all links in a new tab.

Comment: sorry for the late response. Let me try top. Do you also know how I can create a sub menu option that slide the rest of the vertical tile down?

Answer (score 0):

To open the link in the same window I had to use _parent in the as3 script.
But I still don't know how to make the vertical menu bar.